# Why Label controls aren't being hit in a foreach loop if the Label is in a GroupBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Label controls aren't being hit in a foreach loop if the Label is in a GroupBox. If the Labels are outside of a GroupBox they are. How can I get my loop to find them?

```
     foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
     {
         if (c is Label)
         {
             if (c.Text == "12/31/1600")
             {
                 c.Text = "Not Found";
             }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SetLabels (this);

public void SetLabels(Control ctrl)
{
  foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
     {
         SetLabels(c);
         if (c is Label)
         {
             if (c.Text == "12/31/1600")
             {
                 c.Text = "Not Found";
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: You should probably cast c as a Label to check the Text property. ;)

Comment: I dont bother casting because I check `c is label`

Comment: Oops... I didn't realize Control has a Text property, I was thinking WebForms. My bad. haha. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.text.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. That one had me stumped.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
this.groupBox1.Controls
```

in

```
 foreach (Control c in this.groupBox1.Controls)
 {
     if (c is Label)
     {
         if (c.Text == "12/31/1600")
         {
             c.Text = "Not Found";
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I think he wants both the labels in and out of a groupbox. And if there are more groupboxes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion. First of all define a delegate that accept a Control as parameter:

```
public delegate void DoSomethingWithControl(Control c);
```

Then implement a method that takes this delegate as the first parameter, and the control upon which to recursively execute it as the second. This methods first executes the delegates, then loops on the Controls collection of the control to recursively call itself. This works since Controls is defined in Control and returns an empty collection for simple controls like labels:

```
public void RecursivelyDoOnControls(DoSomethingWithControl aDel, Control aCtrl)
{
    aDel(aCtrl);
    foreach (Control c in aCtrl.Controls)
    {
        RecursivelyDoOnControls(aDel, c);
    }
}
```

Now you can put your code for changing the Labels' values in a method and call it on the Form through the delegate:

```
    private void SetLabel(Control c)
    {
        if (c is Label)
        {
            if (c.Text == "12/31/1600")
            {
                c.Text = "Not Found";
            }
        }
    }

RecursivelyDoOnControls(new DoSomethingWithControl(SetLabel), this);
```